# How to post request in Chromedp, simulate a form

Tags: forms, go, post, submit, chromedp

Chromedp have a chromedp.Submit() function which query a form exist in html page and submit it. Now what I need is post a request in pure golang code, there are have no form elements in html page, similar ajax post, this post should base in current context, include cookies, headers. Is it possible to do it this way in Chromedp? Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use `chromedp.Evaluate()` to execute a JavaScript snippet which in turn use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to send the post request. See the demo below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/chromedp/cdproto/runtime"
    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    js := `
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  return response.text();
}; postData('/post', {answer: 69634319})
    `

    var response string
    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate("https://httpbin.org/cookies/set?name=test"),
        chromedp.Evaluate(js, &response, func(ep *runtime.EvaluateParams) *runtime.EvaluateParams {
            return ep.WithAwaitPromise(true)
        }),
    ); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(response)
}
```

If you are curious about the js expression, follow this link for more information: https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/1028#issuecomment-1061482792